# CBC stalling after approximately 10 seconds

Tags: pulp, cbc

I'm using CBC with PuLP to solve a small unit commitment problem.  I'm finding that with certain combinations of input parameters, CBC simply stalls.  With other input parameters, it solves, usually in 10 seconds or so.

I've applied a 20 second time limit, but when it stalls, this is not triggered.

Typically, the last few lines of output are below.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

> Cbc0013I At root node, 182 cuts changed objective from 2190655.4 to 2191172.3 in 20 passes

> Cbc0014I Cut generator 0 (Probing) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 1 column cuts (8 active)  in 2.461 seconds - new frequency is 5

> Cbc0014I Cut generator 1 (Gomory) - 2461 row cuts average 103.2 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.301 seconds - new frequency is 1

> Cbc0014I Cut generator 2 (Knapsack) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.329 seconds - new frequency is 1000

> Cbc0014I Cut generator 3 (Clique) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.016 seconds - new frequency is -100

> Cbc0014I Cut generator 4 (MixedIntegerRounding2) - 553 row cuts average 105.5 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.376 seconds - new frequency is 1

> Cbc0014I Cut generator 5 (FlowCover) - 0 row cuts average 0.0 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.909 seconds - new frequency is -100

> Cbc0014I Cut generator 6 (TwoMirCuts) - 360 row cuts average 89.7 elements, 0 column cuts (0 active)  in 0.516 seconds - new frequency is -100

> Cbc0010I After 0 nodes, 1 on tree, 10044587 best solution, best possible 2191172.3 (11.70 seconds)

Answer (score 4):

CBC does have its fair share of bugs, especially when it comes to proper termination.

If you are running in multithreaded mode try running in serial (or vice-versa), and see if that helps.

If you are feeling particularly adventurous, you can comment out all the code related to the "SIGNAL_TRAP" and recompile CBC. This helps with proper termination (especially when running with timeouts), although it seems to crash more often as a result.